# How to run maven deploy command using java program

Tags: java, maven

How to run Maven deploy(which will deploy to remote nexus repository) command using java Program..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141788/how-to-run-maven-from-java?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313971/how-to-run-a-mvn-command-from-a-java-program?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can use [maven invoker plugin](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/index.html), [here is the basic usage](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/usage.html)