# Which directory should I run mvn from and what does it do?

Tags: java, maven, osx-mavericks

I have searched for: "what does mvn do", and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533828/what-does-mvn-install-in-maven-exactly-do) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313971/how-to-run-a-mvn-command-from-a-java-program) but have not found them useful, because both relate to maven.

I have installed JVM 7-55, and am running Mac OS X 10.9.2

I am trying to build the jar for [log-synth](https://github.com/tdunning/log-synth#) and the instructions call for building the jar file with all dependencies included using:

```
mvn package
```

Where should I run mvn from and what does it do? To be honest I don't even know if the mvn command is Java specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `mvn` is Maven
- `mvn package` runs so called [*package* build phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)
- `mvn` should be always run from a project root directory (i.e. the directory where `pom.xml` is located)
- the built package can be usually located under `target` directory (it will be named something like `log-synth-0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` for the *log synth* project)